# $A,B$ be countable dense subsets of $\mathbb R$ , let $A,B$ be given usual subspace topologies , then there exists a homeomorphism $f:A \to B$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $A,B$ be countable dense subsets of $\mathbb R$ (with usual euclidean topology ) let $A,B$ be given usual subspace topologies , then is it true that there exists a homeomorphism $f:A \to B$ ?

Comment: Yes. See the section on densely ordered sets in [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Comment: @Brian M. Scott : I haven't still read in full detail , but that looks like only order isomorphism , what about continuity ?

Comment: Show that the subspace topology on a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$ actually is the order topology on that subset. It's not quite trivial, but it's not too hard. The denseness is crucial.

Comment: More generally, any metrizable space which is countably infinite and has no isolated points is homeomorphic to the rational numbers.

Comment: There is even a homeomorphism of the reals that restricted to $A$ is a homeomorphism with $B$. This property is called countably dense homogeneous.